# Samba4 share permissions not resolving correctly on server

Tags: samba4, sssd

I'm a bit new to Samba4 and using it as an AD DC. I have a functioning server but seem to be having permissions issues.

Currently, if I create a folder (from Windows) in a Samba share, the permissions on the server (from the command line) are in the range of 3000000.

Winbind isn't in use on this server (Ubuntu 14.04, Samba 4.1.6). I decided to use SSS (v1.11.5) in order to view and apply AD permissions from the command line on the server--this is working fine. But the 3000000+ UIDs/GIDs are not resolving correctly on the server, the UIDs/GIDs in AD are different than the 3000000+ IDs being applied by Samba on the server.

I've kept the configuration pretty basic, I've included the relevant (sanitized) config files below. Please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

```
# smb.conf
[global]
        workgroup = WKGP
        realm = WKGP.LOCAL
        netbios name = SERVER
        server role = active directory domain controller
        dns forwarder = 8.8.8.8
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes

# sssd.conf
[sssd]
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2
domains = WKGP.LOCAL

[domain/WKGP.LOCAL]
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
override_homedir = /srv/samba/Users/%u
krb5_keytab=/etc/sssd/krb5.keytab
```

I should note, too, that Kerberos authentication is working on the server (i.e. I'm able to `kinit administrator@WKGP.LOCAL`) and DNS and all other services appear to be working as well. SSS is also able to `getent passwd user` and successfully retrieve an AD user's account information.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but this won't work with the version you are using.

The CIFS plugin and the libwbclient plugin are features of sssd-1.12.0 and 1.12.1 respectively:

- https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/wiki/Releases/Notes-1.12.0
- https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/wiki/Releases/Notes-1.12.1

(at any rate, if you decide to go with 1.12.x, please do go with 1.12.5, it contains many bug fixes and is generally much more stable than the previous versions)

Comment: Ok, thank you. It's probably going to be several days before I can try this, but I'll respond back once I do.

Comment: Thanks again for your input! Can you direct me to some documentation regarding this please? Your links were useful and I'm now using 1.12.5 on Ubuntu 14.04.2 and have the AD provider working. However, I'm not exactly sure how to get the CIFS or libwbclient stuff working as I've been unable to locate any documentation that explains how to utilize those plugins (both are installed, though).